# Java code declaring a path for a file

Tags: java, tomcat7, filepath

So I have reinstalled tomcat on my server and deployed my old code on it.
I'm having a massive problem with reading and creating files. The error that comes up is "path (access denied)". I checked all the permissions of the folders and they have the correct permissions.

So my question is that maybe because I changed the tomcat version to 7.0.77 from 7.0.23 this occurred? or maybe because different versions of Java jre?

I know I can change the paths from the code but its over 5000 files and I would like to find a faster way to do it.

Comment: It's very unlikely that a minor upgrade of Tomcat or Java could cause this problem. Could you please provide more information about your configuration ?

Comment: @Mickael B. What exactly would you like to know? Its a windows server 2012 R2.